# How to use Roslyn when solution contains projects with different compile options

Tags: roslyn

The initial problem is that I have a huge solution where projects have different options (e.g., x64 or x86 configuration, allow unsafe code or not and so on).
I'm trying to use Roslyn (2.9.0) to compile\parse that solution with DEBUG x64 configuration. Compilation of some projects has failed because 'DEBUG x86' should be used only.

I create a test solution with 'DEBUG x64' configuration.

```
Project A is a console application (DEBUG x64). 
Project B is a library (DEBUG x86)
```

and writing this code:

```
MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();
_workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create(props);
_workspace.SkipUnrecognizedProjects = false;
_solution = _workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionFilePath).Result;
var projectsGpaph = _solution.GetProjectDependencyGraph();
var projects = projectsGpaph.GetTopologicallySortedProjects();
```

**When "props" is not set**

_workspace.Diagnostics is Empty and "projects" have a right order (library, then app)

```
B: project.CompilationOptions.Platform is AnyCpu
A: project.CompilationOptions.Platform is AnyCpu32BitPreferred
```

**When "props" is set to**

```
var props = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"Configuration", "Debug"},
    {"Platform", "x64"}     
};
```

_workspace.Diagnostics is Empty, "projects" have a wrong order:

```
A: project.CompilationOptions.Platform is X64
B: project.CompilationOptions.Platform is X64
```

and an exception has thrown when I execute "project.GetCompilationAsync().Result":

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Reference of type 
'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.UnresolvedMetadataReference' is not valid for this 
compilation.
Parameter name: references[0]'
```

How to force Roslyn to take into account .sln\.csproj settings?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is "It's not supporting to load concrete project's compile options".

As for my problem, I compared the behavior with Roslyn 2.7:

**With Roslyn 2.7:**

When I use "Any CPU" configuration GetTopologicallySortedProjects works correctly on this test solution and my huge solution compiles without errors.

**With Roslyn 2.9:**

I found that project references in ProjectDependencyGraph::_referencesMap are wrong and it looks like the reason is an incorrect implementation of immutable collections.
There are many internal errors when I compile my huge solution (Any CPU) and as a result:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Immutable.Requires.FailArgumentNullException(String parameterName)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.Requires.NotNullAllowStructs[T](T value, String parameterName)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.CommandLineArgumentReader.ReadDebugInfo()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCommandLineArgumentReader.ReadCore()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.CommandLineArgumentReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCommandLineArgumentReader.Read(ProjectInstance project)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpProjectFile.ReadCommandLineArgs(ProjectInstance project)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.ProjectFile.GetCommandLineArgs(ProjectInstance project)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.ProjectFile.CreateProjectFileInfo(ProjectInstance project)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.ProjectFile.<BuildProjectFileInfoAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.ProjectFile.<GetProjectFileInfosAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
```

Comment: I noticed the same problem. ```GetTopologicallySortedProjects()``` returns wrong order. As a result in case when project appears before its dependency you will see ```Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.UnresolvedMetadataReference``` in the project ```MetadataReferences``` property. I downgraded version of Roslyn to 2.7

Answer (score 0):

All properties that are contained in the workspace would be applied to all solution's projects when you will try to open it. Look at the [loader](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Desktop/Workspace/MSBuild/MSBuildWorkspace.cs,33) and look how it will [open solution](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Desktop/Workspace/MSBuild/MSBuildWorkspace.cs,177) and how it [will open](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Desktop/Workspace/MSBuild/MSBuildProjectLoader.cs,156) the each project and apply properties.

In the current API you should create your solution and change the interesting to you properties for all projects by hand. Unfortunately, I know how to change only the project's `Platform`, but not a `Configuration`, therefore you need to post your question to [roslyn home page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). Hovewer, I will show how you can change a `Platform`:

```cs
...
foreach (var project in _solution.Projects.ToList())
{
    // NOTE: you will need to a little "function", that will be convert "x64" to Platform.X64 and so on
    solution = solution.WithProjectCompilationOptions(project.Id, project.CompilationOptions.WithPlatform(Platform.X64));
}
```